# Fillter array by key

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple question, I did it in javascript, but in php everything is different:
In my request when I did dd($request->all()) it returned an array like this

```
$request = [
  'question_ru' => 'question ru',
  'asnwer_ru' => 'answer ru',
  'question_uz' => 'question uz',
  'asnwer_uz' => 'answer uz',
  'question_en' => 'question en',
  'asnwer_en' => 'answer en',
];
```

Now my problem is, I need to write a function which gets two argument: 1) a request, 2) a key and returns an array like this

```
function filter_array_by_key($array, $key) {}

function filter_array_by_key($request, 'title') =>

$result = [
  'title' => [
    'ru' => 'question ru',
    'uz' => 'question uz',
    'en' => 'question en',
  ],
];
```

'JS VERSION'

```
export function filterFormDataByKey(object: Object, key: string) {
  let startNumber = key.length + 1
  const data = lodash.entries(object)

  let filteredObject = {}

  data.forEach((arr) => {
    if (arr[0].startsWith(key)) {
      let innerObj = { [arr[0].slice(startNumber)]: arr[1] }

      Object.assign(filteredObject, innerObj)
    }
  })

  return filteredObject
}
```

and it worked well!

Comment: There is neither a question or a problem here, just a requirement. What have you tried in your PHP attempt at this? Where are you stuck, and what do you need to ask us about it? See also [ask]

Comment: If you control the code that makes the request, you could fix it at the source, posting the data in the format you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filter_array_by_key($array, $key) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $arrayKey => $value) {
        if (strpos($arrayKey, $key) === 0) {
            $langCode = substr($arrayKey, strlen($key) + 1);
            $result[$key][$langCode] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shehara Thrimavithana, your code worked very well, this is what I want, thank you and wish you good luck!

Comment: Wellcome Doston!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return values with that pattern.

```
    Route::get('php/', function () {
    function filter_array_by_key($array, $key)
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($array as $arrayKey => $value) {
            if (strpos($arrayKey, $key . '_') === 0) {
                $language = substr($arrayKey, strlen($key) + 1);
                $result[$key][$language] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    // Example usage with the correct key:
    $request = [
        'question_ru' => 'question ru',
        'answer_ru' => 'answer ru',
        'question_uz' => 'question uz',
        'answer_uz' => 'answer uz',
        'question_en' => 'question en',
        'answer_en' => 'answer en',
        'question_tz' => 'question tz',
        'answer_tz' => 'answer tz',
    ];

    dd(filter_array_by_key($request, 'question'));
});
```